# How do I check if the user's input matches math function results?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a game which creates random math problems for a user on a webpage.  I need to check whether a user's input (their answer) matches the results from the random function.  I have four functions that are randomly called when the "New Problem" button is clicked.  I'd like to see if the user's input matches the function results by displaying, "Correct" or "Incorrect" on the page.  Anybody have any ideas?  I'm fairly new to JS and I'm not sure what to google for this one but I'm willing to look things up. with some direction.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#start')

const randomFunc = [
    multiplication,
    division,
    addition,
    subtraction,
]

btn.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function () {
        randomFunc[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomFunc.length)]();
    }
)

function multiplication() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let problemResult = num1 * num2;
    console.log(num1, '*', num2, '=', problemResult);
    document.getElementById('mathProblem').innerHTML =
    (`${num1} * ${num2} =`);
}

function division() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    let problemResult = (num1 * num2) / num2;
    console.log(num1 * num2, '/', num2, '=', problemResult);
    document.getElementById('mathProblem').innerHTML =
    (`${num1 * num2} / ${num2} =`);
}

function addition() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let problemResult = num1 + num2;
    console.log(num1,'+',num2,'=',problemResult);
    document.getElementById('mathProblem').innerHTML =
    (`${num1} + ${num2} =`);
}

function subtraction() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let numList = [num1, num2];
    numList.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    });
    let problemResult = numList[1] - numList[0];
    console.log(numList[1], '-', numList[0], '=', problemResult);
    document.getElementById('mathProblem').innerHTML =
        (`${numList[1]} - ${numList[0]} =`);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="start" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">New Problem</button>
  <script src={% static 'js/game_logic.js' %}></script>
  <p id="mathProblem">Your problem will appear here</p>
  <form action="">
      <input id="user_input" type="text" placeholder="Type your answer here">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have your functions return `problemResult` and, when the user submits their answer, compare the value that value. Note: you'll first need to harmonise their type - i.e. both to strings or both to ints.

Comment: @Mitya exactly!  I'd like to compare `problemResult` to whatever the user types in the input box.  I just don't know how to connect the input box to `problemResult`.  I think it would be better to make them both integers, that way if the user enters anything besides an integer it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your functions return `problemResult`, store it, and then compare it to the user input when they enter it.

Presently, you're not listening for user input at all. You could do this via a submit button (i.e. the user is expected to click a button when they've finished) or we could listen as they enter data. Let's do the latter:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let result = randomFunc[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomFunc.length)]();
    document.querySelector('#user_input').addEventListener('input', evt => {
        if (result.toString() === evt.target.value) {
            /* correct! do something here */
        } else {
            /* not correct yet... */
        }
    });
})
```

Note how we cast `result` to a string, so we're comparing apples with apples versus the user input (which, coming from a field value, will always be a string.)

Don't forget to adjust your functions to return `problemResult`.

Comment: So at the end of each of my math functions I simply add `return problemResult`?

For the correct and incorrect statements could I have something in the HTML say, "correct" or "incorrect"?  

I also noticed the `result.toString()` function. The `problemResult` is a number, wouldn't this be comparing the user's input (as a string) to the number from `problemResult`?

Comment: I was able to make another button that says, "correct" or "incorrect" depending on the user's answer.  Thanks!

Comment: That's precisely why we harmonise them both to strings before comparison.

Comment: Initially I didn't notice `problemResult`(a number) was getting reassigned to `result`(converted to string).  I was checking the typeof(problemResult) in the console and noticed it was a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the "problemResult" variable globally, and trim the "let" from the other declarations, you can access the value elsewhere. In this example I added a button for checking the answer:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#start')

const randomFunc = [
    multiplication,
    division,
    addition,
    subtraction,
]
var problemResult; //declared globally
btn.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function () {
        randomFunc[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomFunc.length)]();
    }
)

function multiplication() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    problemResult = num1 * num2; // "let" trimmed
    console.log(num1, '*', num2, '=', problemResult);
    document.getElementById('mathProblem').innerHTML =
    (`${num1} * ${num2} =`);
}

function division() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    problemResult = (num1 * num2) / num2; //"let" trimmed
    console.log(num1 * num2, '/', num2, '=', problemResult);
    document.getElementById('mathProblem').innerHTML =
    (`${num1 * num2} / ${num2} =`);
}

function addition() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    problemResult = num1 + num2; //"let" trimmed
    console.log(num1,'+',num2,'=',problemResult);
    document.getElementById('mathProblem').innerHTML =
    (`${num1} + ${num2} =`);
}

function subtraction() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let numList = [num1, num2];
    numList.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    });
    problemResult = numList[1] - numList[0]; //"let" trimmed
    console.log(numList[1], '-', numList[0], '=', problemResult);
    document.getElementById('mathProblem').innerHTML =
        (`${numList[1]} - ${numList[0]} =`);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="start" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">New Problem</button>
  <p id="mathProblem">Your problem will appear here</p>
  <script src={% static 'js/game_logic.js' %}></script>
  <form action="">
      <input id="user_input" type="text" placeholder="Type your answer here">
  </form>
  <button onclick="console.log(document.getElementById('user_input').value == problemResult ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrect')">Check</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This will error. Chances are the OP's script is (or at least should be) running inside a closure, which means `problemResult` is still a *local* variable, not a truly global one. And besides, truly global variables are a really bad idea.

Comment: @Lemondoge Thanks!  I didn't find an error using your method but I agree with Mitya on trying not to use global variables, although it does seem like a good way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You created a class or a div for the element where the user enters the answer. Create a variable that will store the value entered by the user and then use `if()` statement to display the desired result:

```
var input= document.getElementById("user_input");
if(input== problemresult){
    alert(correct); 
} else {
    alert(incorrect);
}
```